# How can I extract the OSM XML files of any urban City map?

Tags: openstreetmap, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am studying UVCAST protocol for vehicular ad hoc networks with infrastructure (RSU).there is RSU Application that will apply on the RSU and UVCAST that will apply on the Vehicles in my code  (.cc,.h,.ned ) that wrote according to the studied protocol that they depend on BaseWaveApplLayer `#include "veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h"` for RSU Application.h/UVCAST.h and `import org.car2x.veins.modules.application.ieee80211p.BaseWaveApplLayer;` for RSU Application.ned/UVCAST.ned and also depend on

```
const simsignalwrap_t RSUApplication::mobilityStateChangedSignal = simsignalwrap_t(MIXIM_SIGNAL_MOBILITY_CHANGE_NAME);
```

and also there are Beacon messages and Data messages

```
#include "veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage_m.h" 
#include "veins/base/utils/Coord.h"
```

in my code. How can I extract the OSM XML files of any urban city with very very large area and the Values of playgroundSizeX ,playgroundSizeY,playgroundSizeZ are large without spending long time on the internet ?.because I want to get many events(accidents,alerts,....) during many TimeEvents: TimeEvent=1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 5400, 6300 with sim-time-limit = 7290s or TimeEvent=23400, 24300, 25200, 26100, 27000, 27900, 66600, 67500, 68400, 69300, 70200, 71100 with sim-time-limit = 86400s(full day) in omnet.ini

```
*.rsu[*].appl.startDataProductionTime = ${TimeEvent=1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 5400, 6300}s
```

for the first Scenario

```
*.rsu[*].appl.startDataProductionTime = ${TimeEvent=23400, 24300, 25200, 26100, 27000, 27900, 66600, 67500, 68400, 69300, 70200, 71100}s
```

for the second Scenario.
If I applied that on medium or small area (the values of playgroundSizeX ,playgroundSizeY,playgroundSizeZ are not large, this means dataROI is not large ), We maybe don't have any events when I execute the Scenario for TimeEvent=6300s for example or another value of TimeEvent  ,so I will get the same results for different TimeEvents.

note: I am using GatComSumo.jar with Sumo/bin path, I want to suggest me another application(tool) to extract OSM XML files of my map (.launched,.ned,.rou,.poly,.osm,.sumo.cfg,omnetini,......) without spending long time on the internet to simulate them with the studied protocol.
please reply on my question .

Comment: Please spend few minutes formatting your question. That's such a wall of text that I doubt anyone wants to read it like that.

Comment: I edited my question .please if you can answer on my question , rewrite your suggestions .

Comment: Still no formatting whatsoever. Huge block of text.

Comment: I edited  and improved my question  again .please if you can answer on my question , rewrite your suggestions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing, if it is how to extract OSM XML for simulations, you can use openstreetmap. If it is how to accelerate a simulation if you use a bit map, this is more complex, bigger scenarios implies more events and more events implies more simulation time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I have answers about all the question that you mentioned .